# What is the difference between navigationController.navigationBarHidden and navigationController.navigationBar.hidden?

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationbar, navigationbar

I found the hard way that

```
navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
```

and

```
navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = NO;
```

are not the same thing.  In fact, if I use the first syntax to hide the nav bar, then I cannot use the second syntax to show it: it simply won't do anything.  Moreover, the first syntax to show/hide the nav bar always works for me, while the second syntax works some times, but not always.  I haven't been able to determine exactly when it would work and when not.

As I was stuck with fixing somebody else's code (a reasonably large app: over 20 UIViewControllers), I had to do a global search for `navigationBar.hidden` and replace it with `navigationBarHidden`.  After that, I had to do a global search for `navigationBar setHidden:` and replace with `navigationBarHidden` syntax.  This eventually fixed the issue.

Yet, I want to understand why the two different options are provided and what the real difference between them is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

navigationBarHidden applies an animation when hiding or showing the navBar duration of this navigation could be set by using UINavigationControllerHideShowBarDuration

Where navigationBar.hidden will directly change the visiblity status of the `UINavigationBar` (which is a subclass of `UIView`)

Since `UINavigationBar` is a subclass of `UIView` it inherited the hidden bool property, no way of changing it to protected or private

From [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

> The navigation controller is responsible for managing the
>   configuration and display of the navigation bar and navigation
>   toolbar. You must never modify these views directly. Instead, you
>   should manipulate them through the methods and properties of the
>   UINavigationController class. You can hide and show the navigation bar
>   using the navigationBarHidden property or
>   setNavigationBarHidden:animated: method.

Comment: Ok, it starts making sense.  This means that I shouldn't be using `navigationBar.hidden` directly, but use `navigationBarHidden` instead - right?

Comment: yes this seems to be the case, since you have an explicit property that hides and shows the navBar

Comment: Ok, this now makes total sense.  Thanks.

Comment: @OmarAbdelhafith Why shouldn't we use `UIView's @hidden` property directly? Does the default value of `UINavigationController's @navigationBarHidden` property overrides it?